# Let $A, B \in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1.$ Show that $\det(A + \sqrt{2}\cdot B) \not= 0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1.$ Show that $\det(A + \sqrt{2}\cdot B) \not = 0.$

I tried a bunch of techniques but nothing seems to work. Usually one can factorize expressions using complex numbers but there the matrices do not commute. Perhaps solutions using eigenvalues can be used. Since the determinant is non-zero we can claim that the eigenvalues are non-zero. But what does that say about the sum, I am not sure. I also tried to show that the columns of the matrix $A+\sqrt{2}B$ are independent but that get's messy. And lastly I tried to construct the following linear polynomial:

$$|A+xB|=p(x)$$ then $p(x)=ax+b$ and since $p(0)=1$ we have that $p(x)=ax+1.$ But what should I do after this, I am again not sure. Any ideas/hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if $A$ is the diagonal matrix $diag(-\sqrt2,1,-1/\sqrt2)$ and $B$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: @Masacroso, while each of the trwo matrice can be made upper triangular, in general you cannot do that simultaneously for both.

Comment: @Masacroso No, determinant $1$ does not imply the eigenvalues are $1$. For example, $(1/2)(1/2)(4)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. There exist matrices with determinant $1$ such that the first row of $A$ is $(-\sqrt 2,0,0)$ and the first row of $B$ is $(1,0,0)$.

Are you sure the problem said  $A, B \in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{C})$ ? It's been hinted that the problem is right for  $A, B \in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{Z})$. That seemed totally obvious at first, then thinking about it it wasn't so obvious for a minute. I think the following's correct - there's probably a less clumsy way:

If we had a counterexample with integer entries then $M=AB^{-1}$ would be a matrix with integer entries, determinant $1$, with an eigenvalue $-\sqrt 2$. Since the minimal polynomial for $-\sqrt 2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $t^2-2$ it follows that $t^2-2$ divides the characteristic polynomial for $M$, so $\sqrt 2$ is also an eigenvalue. Since $\det(M)=1$ the third eigenvalue is $-1/2$, but now the sum of the eigenvalues is not an integer.

In fact there *is* a matrix $M$ with rational entries having determinant $1$ and $-\sqrt 2$ for an eigenvalue, namely $$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&2&0
\\1&0&0
\\0&0&-1/2\end{bmatrix}.$$And sure enough if $A=M$, $B=I$ then $A$ and $B$ have determinant $1$ while $\det(A+\sqrt 2B)=0$.

Comment: https://lupucezar.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/worksheet_linear_algebra__undergraduate_competitions_.pdf   (See problem number 6).

Comment: Did you read the problem?

Comment: I feel like mathematicians need to forge a word that encapsulates "a large embarrassing and glaring error passed off as truth that a second pair of eyes quickly saw."

Comment: @SuperMario Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to give you a credible(?) source. So do you think $\mathbb{C}$ should be replaced with $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @SuperMario That's one way to fix it, yes.

Comment: So can I argue as follows: If $|A+\sqrt{2}B|=0$ then $p=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ So we have that $|A+xB|=1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}.$ But if $x$ is an integer then $|A+xB|$ is an integer however $1-1/\sqrt{2}$ is not hence a contradiction. Does this argument work?

Comment: @SuperMario I have no idea what the argument you have in mind is - what is "$p$"?

Comment: The polynomial I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @SuperMario Oh right. I didn't get that at all. Why do you say $p$ is linear? It seems obviously cubic to me. Anyway, I added an argument for $\Bbb Z$ to the answer...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ by $\pi$.

Proposition. Let $K$ be a field and $u$ be transcendental over $K$. Let $A,B\in M_n(K)$ s.t. $\det(B)\not=0$. Then $\det(A+uB)\not= 0$.

Proof. $\det(A+uB)=u^n \det(B)+\sum_{i<n}a_ix^i$ where $\det(B)\in K\setminus 0$ and $a_i\in K$. If $\det(A+uB)=0$, then $u$ is algebraic over $K$, a contradiction.